# How to do Lua math random exception

Tags: random, lua, except

I need a little help with some Lua code. The idea is to get a random number `0`- `18` but it cannot be number `8` or `16`. How can I do this?

```
self.currentSkyTexture = math.random(0,18)
```

-- not `8` or `16`... how?

Answer (score 4):

Make a table of answers

```
local rans = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,18}
```

Choose from the table

```
function myRandom() return rans[math.random(#rans)] end
```

This chooses one entry from the table with uniform probability, and makes one call to `math.random` for each.

Comment: Is the double `15` on the list intentional or just a typo?

Comment: @greatwolf, it's a typo

Answer (score 2):

Just check if it's 8 or 16 and re-run the random as long as it's one of those.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are only 2 exceptions in the 19 possible random numbers, the brute force method won't cause performance problem.

```
function myRandom()
    local ret
    repeat
        ret = math.random(0,18)
    until ret ~= 8 and ret ~= 16
    return ret
end

self.currentSkyTexture = myRandom()
```

Comment: If this is the sort of random that @WerewolF will be doing often this is a more elegant, DRY solution.

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest case, you can replace exclusions by directly checking for them:

```
function skipRandom()
    local ret = math.random(0,16)
    if ret == 8 then 
        ret = 17 
    elseif ret == 16 then 
        ret = 18 
    end
    return ret
end

self.currentSkyTexture = skipRandom()
```

Comment: What makes you think it will run faster than a table lookup? Have you benchmarked the alternatives?

Comment: Nope, but you made me curious about my assumptions. In lua-5.1, mine is 5% faster. In 5.2 yours is 5% faster, and in luajit 2.0.3, yours is 8% faster than mine. And in all cases, repeated calls to random are 10-15% slower than the loser.

Comment: I ran a microbenchmark on a tiny (Atom processor) Debian Wheezy Lua 5.2.1, and the two approaches are pretty comparable; for 10,000,000 iterations, skipRandom 0m8.138s; table based myRandom 0m7.509s

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, this will generate the exclusion arrays and functions for specific parameters:

```
function makeExcludedRandom(min,max,exclude)
    local values = {}
    local i = 0
    local j = 0
    table.sort(exclude)
    while i < max-min-1 do
       while exclude[j+1] == min+i+j do
          j = j + 1
       end

       values[i+1]=min+i+j
       i=i+1
    end

    return function()
        return values[math.random(min,max)]
    end
end    
local skipRandom = makeExcludedRandom(0,18,{8,16})

self.currentSkyTexture = skipRandom()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution (if using low amount of numbers use first answer).

```
function randomize()
    local r = math.random(0,18);
    if (r == 8 or r == 16) then 
        return randomize();
    end
    return r;
end
```